# How to add custom filter in header in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

In my magento site,
I have there drop down list in header, I want to search Or navigate product after last drop down item select. drop down are dependent each other (i mean third depends on second, second depends on first) third drop down are attributes values of the second drop down category item.
it should be work like filters. I have create .phtml file and have added these drop down in header. please help me out.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: i have solve this issue. but for that i have write some hard code for particulate attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customise your layered navigation functionality

An example of layered navigation with your problem

You have 3 attributes:- (Category,Color, Manufacaturer) Color is dependent on category and Manufacturer in Color

So when you pass #cat=5 the ajax call will filter out the products. Also filter out the second dropdown according to available products existing color.. Then similarly pass #cat=5&color=23.... so on

This filteration is already done in layered navigation. You just have to custmise your code to use this in dropdown

:)